# Aws Textract Tables and Rawtext in a single document

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, ocr, amazon-textract, paddleocr

I am using Amazon Textract to extract data from pdf files to an s3 location. My documents consist of Tables and Paragraphs. when I parse through the extract i get the raw text of all data however the table data is distorted.
Below is the actual image. The data is read line or word by word but not the contents on the Table within or inside a block. Is it possible to get the block data in  raw text as if i choose tables it ignores rest of the stuff not in table

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g81Sh.png)